# Can Fuse ESB implement message broker and message queue

Tags: message, activemq-classic, mule, esb, fuseesb

I'm a really newbie in ESB (you can say no experience).
And actually I haven't really understood the real meaning of ESB.

My expectation of ESB is a middleware that can connect to whatever the client is
(.NET, Flex, Ajax, Android, etc.).
And I expect that ESB can implement MESSAGE QUEUE.
Cause I'm really really interested in message queue.

I just tried Mule ESB.
I successfully created SOA request-response.
But it seems that Mule ESB doesn't have message queue.

**AND MY QUESTION IS**:
Is it possible for Fuse ESB to implement message queue?

Thank you,

Rizki Sunaryo

Answer (score 2):

Yes Fuse ESB has a message broker embedded (its Apache ActiveMQ). So you have that out of the box with Fuse ESB.

You can also with Fuse ESB connect to an external message broker of choice, using JMS as the protocol. For example to connect to a WebSphereMQ, WebLogicAQ, etc.

There is also a standalone Fuse MQ product that is just the message broker. So if you only want a messaging system, then you can go for Fuse MQ.

You can find some details here

- http://fusesource.com/products/fuse-esb-enterprise/
- http://fusesource.com/products/fuse-mq-enterprise/

Red Hat has since acquired FuseSource so the Fuse products is being rebranded as JBoss Fuse, and JBoss A-MQ. You can find details here:

- http://www.redhat.com/products/jbossenterprisemiddleware/fuse
- http://www.redhat.com/products/jbossenterprisemiddleware/amq/